# Portable Ubuntu cannot Boot into New Systems with High Graphic Cards

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, graphics, portable

Hello I am trying to solve my problems for days but couldn't find any solution so here is the story and the question:

I have created a portable Ubuntu 18.04 following this guide https://www.fosslinux.com/10212/how-to-install-a-complete-ubuntu-on-a-usb-flash-drive.htm . I have also added another EFI partition as the installation prompted me to do so.

I have completed these steps on an old machine with:

Intel 2nd Gen. i7 CPU,
nVidia GT630M GPU,
12 GB of RAM

The portable Ubuntu runs in the old system so far but when I switch the computers, Ubuntu just stuck at a full black screen after the 5 dots are passed.

The new system has the following hardware configuration:

Intel 8th Gen. i7 CPU,
nVidia GTX1070M GPU,
24 GB of RAM

So if anyone has encountered the same problem or any solution I will appreciate your answers. If you have any advice on reinstalling Ubuntu on the USB I can also do that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It can help other people with the same or similar problems :-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer to your question (the solution) inside the question. Please use the "Answer my own question" button below and write your own answer. Then you can accept your own answer as the correct one with the green check mark ✅ or leave the ✅ as is.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a year my system worked with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have found the following guide:

https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/fixing-the-problems-installing-ubuntu-on-asus-rog-laptop-asus-gl503ge-5b6f497201b8

I did not changed anything from BIOS and booted from installation USB. From the options I selected **Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)** and added *nouveau.modeset=0* to the boot options as the reply and guide directed.

My USB size is 128 GB and partition table is something like this:

- / :64 GB (root)
- /swap :20 GB (swap)
- /home: 40 GB

After installing I added the nVidia graphics drivers from Software Updater. Touchpad and all the other hardware work normally except the nVidia sound card (Which is a very common issue as I understand; if I find a solution to that, I will add it also here).

Thanks for your help!